# JS - Search String with quotes as well as without quotes via regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, search, filter

I would like to be able to perform the following, using examples based on my code:

- Search for Carpenter Company returns 2 records
- Search for "Carpenter Company" (with the double quotation marks) returns 1 record

I couldn't get it to work so far, also tried to combine the regex with the following expression:

```
"[\w\s]+\"
```

Here is my plunker sample:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SqFOqqiRG7oFXHY89o6e?p=preview

And specifically the code part I am looking into:

```
    var app = angular.module('filter', [])
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.deals = [{
    lob: 'Marine, Motor, Carpenter',
    cedent: 'ABC Paris Company',
    treaty: 'QS - Test'
  }, {
    lob: 'Liability',
    cedent: 'Carpenter Company',
    treaty: 'W/XL Test'
  }];
});

// filterBy implementation
app.filter('filterBy', function() {
  return function(array, query) {
    var parts = query  && query.trim().split(/\s+/g) ,
      keys = Object.keys(array[0]);
    if (!parts || !parts.length) return array;
    return array.filter(function(obj) {
      return parts.every(function(part) {
        return keys.some(function(key) {
          return String(obj[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(part.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Thank you in advance for some hints how to solve it.

Comment: Try [this code](http://plnkr.co/edit/s2ereuGWI4SW6IOHCEU2?p=preview).

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks a lot for your swift reply. This works fine for the purpose I stated in my question. But what if I want to combine it, for example search for: "Company Country" Test it should return one record too. Any suggestions how to solve that in an elegant way?

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks a lot! But what if I want to combine it, for example search for: "Company Country" Test it should return one record too. Any suggestions how to solve that in an elegant way?

Comment: Are you going to support any escaped quotes/symbols?

Comment: @stribizhev No, not necessarily.

Comment: Good riddle! Made me think a bit. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the code a bit to collect the search keywords from the input:

```
app.filter('filterBy', function() {
  return function(array, query) {
    if (!query) return array;                    // Added for better error checking
    var parts = query  && get_query(query.trim()) , // Use the get_query function here
      keys = Object.keys(array[0]);
    if (!parts || !parts.length) return array;
    return array.filter(function(obj) {
      return parts.every(function(part) {
        return keys.some(function(key) {
          return String(obj[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(part.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
      });
    });
  };
});

function get_query(qry) {      // Function to collect search keywords
  var re = /"([^"]+)"|\S+/g;   // The regex gets all "..." or
  var m;                       //  non-whitespace substrings
  var res = [];
  while ((m = re.exec(qry)) !== null) { 
    res.push(m[1] ? m[1] : m[0]);      // Get either the captured text inside ""
  }                                    // or a non-whitespace chunk
```

Here is an [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fkf4yJY4Mzlu7zuTo8A8?p=preview)

Comment: This is wonderful! Works like a charm, thanks a lot for that! I'd say this should be the accepted answer to my question. Unfortunately, I cannot mark it as such as I don't have the rights on SO yet.

Comment: You actually marked it as accepted, but you cannot *upvote* it yet. You will be able to upvote once your reputation grows to 15 points.